# Convert server UTC time to client local time

Tags: c#, c++, timezone, filetime

I get from server native (C++) application a FILETIME structure in UTC format. On the managed (C#) client side I need to show it as client(!) local time. Do I need along with FILETIME transfer information about server time zone to accomplish this? Or such information already contains in FILETIME in UTC format?

Comment: It is not "server UTC time", it is "UTC time". TC is absolute and not machine depenadnt (unless the clock on the machine is simply set wrong).

Answer (score 7):

#### Description

You can convert a UTC DateTime to local Time using `TimeZoneInfo`

#### Sample

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(YourDateTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

You can convert a UTC DateTime to any timezone, if you know the name. For example.

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(YourDateTime, 
                TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"));
```

#### More Information

- [TimeZoneInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx)
- [How to: Instantiate a TimeZoneInfo Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397765.aspx)

Comment: But how do I found out the client TimeZone? TimeZoneInfo.Local returns the SERVER's.

Comment: Do you mean in a ASP.NET Application ?

Comment: Yes, I was regarding a webapp but I guess its not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

```
create a class
public class TimeConverter
    {
        public static DateTime ConvertToLocalTime(DateTime utcTime, string timeZoneId)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(timeZoneId))
            {
                return utcTime;
            }
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(utcTime, timeZoneId);
        }
}

In controller use TimeConverter

TimeConverter.ConvertToLocalTime(Date, yourTimeZone));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your structure is, but if you can convert it to standard time string, DateTime class will parse it. Then simply use the ToLocalTime method.

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(FILETIME.ToString());
time.ToLocalTime();
```