# C# and Current Local time for different countries

Tags: c#, date, datetime, cultureinfo

C# offers a way to get the current date by `DateTime.Now`. But the problem is my server is on US and I get the US time when I use `DateTime.Now`

Is there any way to get the current local time for a specific country in C# as my users are from around the world? (I have locale of each user, so if I Can get the current time for each locale then I’m safe)

I've seen a way [using Time Zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066303/how-to-get-current-time-of-different-countries-in-c-sharp) but then I have to keep time zone vs country reference.

I’ve searched and most of the question here is about converting UTC time to local time and vice versa. Hope someone would be able to enlighten me.

Comment: I dont offer a solution, but read the blog [Whats wrong with datetime anyway](http://noda-time.blogspot.in/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html) for the problems related to DateTime/DateTimeOffet. .

Comment: [Get timezone by Country and Region](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7977736)

Comment: Note that some countries span over several timezones. So knowing only the country may not be enough. Better knowing directly the user timezone from his computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save your time in your server using UTC time `(DateTime.UtcNow)` and then depending on the users time zone you will change this utc time.  Never save local time in the db

Comment: Have you read [Whats wrong with datetime anyway](http://noda-time.blogspot.in/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html). DateTime + local timezone + Day Light saving is not as simple to solve as it appears

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614323/convert-server-utc-time-to-client-local-time

Comment: Is it the same as DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()?

Comment: But how can I get the user time zone?

Answer (score 3):

Just look at the [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) class. You should be able to convert to and from local to server time through there while maintaining DST (Daylight Savings time).

```
DateTimeOffset newTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AppTimeZone"));
```

You can also find an Open Source Time Zone Implementation by one of the Great Jon Skeet [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/)